# querySelectorAll problems with pseudo selectors in parentNode

Tags: javascript, dom

I've a structure like this:

```
<div>
  <a></a>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

And I have all p's already in a *real* array:

```
var p = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('div p') );
```

I could grab the first item with `p[0]` but I need the `first-child` (which in this case is the same) so I tried `querySelectorAll` but I get no results doing this:

```
p.forEach(function( el ) {
  console.log( el.parentNode.querySelectorAll('p:first-child') ) //=> empty
});
```

If I do `el.parentNode.querySelectorAll(':first-child')` I get the `<a>` which is not what I want. How do I filter the `first-child` p's in my array?

**Edit:** I tried creating a dummy element and recreating the structure with clones to find my element, although it kinda works I'm not sure it's the best idea...

Comment: The `:first-child` means, really, **first** child of **any** type. What you want is the CSS3 `first-of-type` pseudo-class, which I don't think is very widely supported now.

Comment: @Pointy, Of course, silly me for not reading the spec. You can post that as answer.

Comment: BTW, for `:first-child` you may use `querySelector()` method instead.

Comment: Also, I guess that's why I was getting the "kinda works" behavior with my other attempt with clones. What a waste of time...

Comment: @VisioN: Yeah now that I know what it does exactly I thinks that would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `first-of-type` pseudo-class in CSS3.  I don't think it's very widely supported. The `first-child` pseudo class is a predicate that selects elements of any type that are the first things in their parents child node lists. Because the `<a>` comes first, it's the only thing that'd "hit" with `:first-child`.

*edit* — whoa actually `:first-of-type` seems to be pretty well supported now, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com).

Comment: Wow. Nice link!. All I care actually is IE9+ for this so that's good. Imma use it then.

Comment: Hey! `:first-of-type` was declared in CSS3 and the first time I hear about it. That's +1 for a good surprise :)